# Stripe - Update quantity in trial period , How it works?

Tags: stripe-payments

Ok, so here is the thing, I have an application with stripe integration which includes

- Create customer
- Create subscription
- 30 days trial period
- Option to Update Quantity

1 Quantity here is 99$

Now if i am in active period everything works fine in regards to updating quantity in the middle of the month it creates invoice immediately, but if i am in trial period and i am updating the quantity from 1 to 2
the invoice generated next month is of the quantity 1 only, why is that?

And what is the ideal way of handling this?

Here is the code to update quantity

```
await this.stripeClient.subscriptions.update(stripe_subscription_id, {
                proration_behavior: 'create_prorations',
                items: [{
                    id: subscriptionItemId,
                    price: price,
                    quantity: quantity, //New increased quantity
                }],
                metadata: {
                    user_id: user_id,
                    locations: locations,
                    subscription_type: plan.recurring.interval,
                    stripe_price_id: price,
                },
            });
```

I now doubt, is it possible to update quantity in trial periods, in a way that it remains free in trial period and then get added when next month invoice is created.

Comment: Could you share some code for how you update the quantity?

Comment: sure @karllekko, see the code above

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason for that code to work differently if the subscription is on a trial. Maybe contact Stripe's support with some specific examples of what you see.

Comment: @karllekko ,so from what I understood is that the code I have written will work fine with active subscription, but when you are in trial period you can’t update quantity of subscriptions.